# Sum of special series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that

$\sum_{r=2}^{100} 3^r(\frac{2-2r}{(r+1)(r+2)}) = \frac 12 - \frac {3^{100}}{100(101)}$

I assume that it's an arithmetico geometric series.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: can you clarify the right side of your equation with parentheses

Comment: did you mean $\frac 12 - \frac {3^{100}}{100(101)}$?

Comment: @horse, yes that's what I meant